# php sort multidimensional array by key in nested array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a inner array by integers...
This is the array:

```
  2018 => array:3 [▼
    "08" => array:3 [▼
      1 => 1
      8 => 2
      2 => 1
    ]
    "07" => array:2 [▼
      2 => 2
      1 => 8
    ]
    "05" => array:1 [▼
      1 => 16
    ]
  ]
```

and I want sort this array so that it is this result:

```
 2018 => array:3 [▼
    "08" => array:3 [▼
      1 => 1
      2 => 1
      8 => 2
    ]
    "07" => array:2 [▼
      1 => 8
      2 => 2
    ]
    "05" => array:1 [▼
      1 => 16
    ]
  ]
```

I try with nested array_walk and ksort, but this does not work:

```
array_walk($statistics, function ($a) {
        array_walk($a, 'ksort');
    });
```

> EDIT:

got it myself this is the solution:

```
        array_walk($statistics, function (&$a) {
            array_walk($a, function (&$b) {
                ksort($b);
            });
        });
```

Comment: I think if you search SO for the title of your question, you may just find the right answer easily. Has it occurred to you to give it a try?

Comment: or probably just use a simple foreach and ksort should suffice

Comment: yes I had search, and found only answers with associative arrays. Not for my specific case. I have updated my question because I found the solution by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$sortedStatistics = array_map(function($year) {
    return array_map(function($month) {
        ksort($month);
        return $month;

    }, $year);
}, $statistics);
```